# Is close voting too strict?

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close, moderators

I completely agree there is a need for moderators and users with high rep to stop spammers or completely irrelevant questions. I do not agree with moderators and users with lots of ‘rep’ abusing their power and closing questions that shouldn’t have been; some comments seeming more ego-boosting rather than helpful and explaining why.

There are countless times a question of mine has been closed due to some parameter, normally due to one line that may have opened up the question a bit more. Is the point of Stack Exchange not to spread accurate knowledge?

I’ve seen well thought-out, well-put questions where someone has obviously spent a long time writing only to be closed. Closing question after question for minute reasons seems incredibly counter intuitive and frustrating.

CERTAIN moderators and high-rep are sucking the fun out of Stack Exchange.

Has it gone too far or are these totalitarian actions necessary to keep the page regimented?

Comment: `CERTAIN moderators and high-rep are sucking the fun out of Stack Exchange.` It is not supposed to be fun, if you fine fun helping people, great but this is a serious site for people who need help, not a playground.

Comment: I suggest not starting a post with conjecture about downvotes, take downs or deletions. Starting that way is just asking for it.

Comment: Well, let's see if we can make something out of this. First of all, are you asking in general across all SE sites or for a specific site? Close reasons and topicness are very site-dependent so it is hard to come up with an overall answer. Can you share examples of questions that were closed where you feel this shouldn't be done?

Comment: So I have heard @MarkKirby My point is that asking questions becomes such a laborious task in order to fulfill every requirement over fear that a moderator will shut the question. There must be an element of fun in Stack Exchange for everyone otherwise no one would be here.

Comment: Can you give some generic examples of the kinds of comments you're talking about, even if not linking to specific examples (it's actually probably better if you don't name specific users / comments at this point in your post, but feel free to [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) directly with links). You're missing a lot of needed context here, but maybe we can salvage the discussion :)

Comment: No, no need for an element of fun. So long as the site is **useful**, fun doesn't (and probably **shouldn't**) come into it. You can go to chat to have as much fun as you want.

Comment: Some people get their fun by helping others, me, I use it as a learning tool to solve promles I don't face in my life, that is fun for me. Others enjoy earning rep and others badges. The fun is where you find it. This might go better if you could give an example of mods or high rep user doing something they should not but many of us do find fun in a serious environment.

Comment: It may be worth familiarising yourself with the Help Centre provided by each SE site, prior to asking your question. This may provide guidance and help you avoid asking questions deemed inappropriate by moderators/respected users. :-)

Comment: @TimPost is right I'm not here to name names, I'm just talking about the site in general. Comments that may include some opinion but do not take anything away from the question which can still be answered without a massive long discussion.

Comment: Question askers are probably the one group that really doesn't need to have a motivation of "fun" to play a suitable role. After all, they already have a much stronger motivation. They want answers! Which is why if their questions don't make the cut to be generally useful on the site, they are denied those.

Answer (score 12):

First, welcome to the internet, where sensibilities and common courtesy can often take a back seat to trolling and sensationalism. That being said, there is an [age-old idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/When+in+Rome) that applies to this situation:

> When in Rome(, do as the Romans do).

The close votes, while frustraiting, are meant to help you clarify the question.  Text, in-and-of-itself is a pretty "lean" form of communication (e.g. I can't see you to gauge your emotions, I can't ask questions in real-time to ask for clarifications, etc.).  Your question may make sense when you, the original poster, is composing it but you also have exclusive access to all the contextual information that made you want to ask it in the first place.  That context is likely what's missing and for many users, makes the question difficult to understand.

*Why close questions at all?*  Closing a question prevents additional answers, and really when a random user comes across your question in 6 months, they'll have no idea why all these off-topic answers are being posted on your (hopefully) re-opened and clear question.  Think about how people will interact with the question in 6 months' time and understand confusion is the last thing a Q&A site wants to be be known for.

**My advice is don't take a close vote *personally***.  The close vote isn't about you or even your question's intent; it's likely about the lack of context and the fact that without that context, it's hard to understand.  Make changes to help clear it up and ask to reopen it or post a better, modified version of it.

Answer (score 8):

> I completely agree there is a need for moderators and users with high rep to stop spammers or completely irrelevant questions.

Good, that is settled then.

> I do not agree with moderators and users with lots of ‘rep’ abusing their power and closing questions that shouldn’t have been; some comments seeming more ego-boosting rather than helpful and explaining why.

I see this abuse sentiment brought up often but the only people that have the real option to *abuse* powers are either SE developers or SE Community Moderators. And I have yet to see that abuse to happen. Leaves us with (elected) Moderators and users with moderation privileges. Although moderators have binding close and delete votes, their actions can and will be scrutinized by other community members. Users with a gold tag can unilateral close vote a question as a duplicate. That is useful as the asker gets their answer immediately. For all other moderation action multiple users need to follow a vote, so if power is abused, it needs to be organized power. And once an action is completed, reversing it is possible. After editing a closed question goes into the re-open queue were 5 members will vote.

As for the ego-boosting comments: I'm only here to show off I'm smarter then everyone else.

> There are countless times a question of mine has been closed due to some parameter, normally due to one line that may have opened up the question a bit more. Is the point of Stack Exchange not to spread accurate knowledge?

Yes, and if your question is closed obviously there isn't enough basis to guarantee that future visitors will grasp the context so before wrong answers come in, the question is closed so it can be edited into shape, either by the OP or by the community. And once completed it can be re-opened and answered to become part of the canonical collection of high quality questions and answers.

> I’ve seen well thought-out, well-put questions where someone has obviously spent a long time writing only to be closed. Closing question after question for minute reasons seems incredibly counter intuitive and frustrating.

I hardly believe this is true but without examples hard to counter. What I do see on one of the sites I'm active on (and where I'm one of the prolific close voters) that users assume anything goes on an SE site. If a well-put question is asked at the wrong site, it will be closed. Topicness can be complex and so is finding the right site to ask a question. Hence the site meta's have numerous posts about this as well as questions in the tag [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) to find the correct site. Keep in mind that closure is not the end of a question. When you have a good case and bring it to the site meta I don't see why re-opening shouldn't be the outcome.

> CERTAIN moderators and high-rep are sucking the fun out of Stack Exchange.

The opposite is true. Certain moderators and high-rep users care so much about the quality of the content on their site that they spend many hours on moderating, commenting, editing, voting and fleshing out policy on meta to make sure their site keeps attracting new visitors. They have to deal now and then with new users that find it hard to work out which question goes where and what is or what is not on-topic. Many have done that for years now, we know what we have to deal with.

> Has it gone too far or are these totalitarian actions necessary to keep the page regimented?

I like the idea that I'm part of the totalitarian state you assume SE is and can use the privileges the community trusted me with. I personally think we are not going far enough, specially on high-traffic sites, so keeping a strict protocol and policy helps to make sure both the current users and future visitors find the content useful and of high quality. That is still the reason why the SE sites are different from Yahoo! Answers.